identify how many times same vehicle was captured in the provided video
Working on Video analysis assignment where I need to capture how many times same vehicle was captured in given video.
So far using YOLO11 was able to identify the vehicles such cars, bike, bus & truck. Accordingly drawing rects as vehicles appears in the video frame.
I could not make out, how to mark a vehicle with some identification code. so that, when same vehicle appears in the video frame i can increase count of that vehicle.
Adding my code which I tried
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from enum import Enum

class DetectionType(Enum):
    CAR         = 2
    MOTORCYCLE  = 3
    BUS         = 5
    TRUCK       = 6


coco_model = YOLO('yolo11n.pt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('testVideo.mp4')

vehicles = [
            DetectionType.CAR.value, 
            DetectionType.MOTORCYCLE.value, 
            DetectionType.BUS.value,
            DetectionType.TRUCK.value
            ]

ret = True

while ret:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        #detect vehicle
        detections_model = coco_model(frame)[0]

        for detection in detections_model.boxes.data.tolist():
            x1, y1, x2, y2, score, class_id = detection

            if int(class_id) in vehicles:
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        
    # Display frames in a window 
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
  

    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

Any suggestion or snippet will help me to complete this assignment.

Using Yolo tracker I was able to solve my solution.
Adding snippet here
replace these lines:
detections_model = coco_model(frame)[0]

To this:
detections_model = coco_model.track(frame, persist=True)
track_ids = detections_model[0].boxes.id.int().cpu().tolist()

